# Engine of Office Addins in Windows Desktop

Tags: office-js

Is there any plan to upgrade Windows Desktop host engine from Internet Explorer to Edge or something better?

IE doesn't support the new wave of ECMAScript concepts, and that would impact TypeScript, that is the best way I learned to code Office Addins. Also, there are a number of security reasons why IE should not be used anymore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This topic comes up fairly often and while there would be some notable benefits to using Edge, it presents a number of non-trivial challenges. The most prominent being that Office 2016 supports Windows 7, 8, and 10 while Edge is only available on 10.

Leveraging Edge would require each Office application to support two distinct embedded browsers dependent on the version of Windows it is installed on. More importantly, even if this path were taken you would still need to support IE as your add-in could be run in either environment (not to mention the Online and Mac editions).

As to the TypeScript question, this issue has been with us for a long time. As much as we all would love to start using new features like mix-ins in our web apps, the nature of JS in the wild will always present challenges. It takes a long time for new ECMA features to become widely available across browsers and platforms. ECMAScript 6 was finalized in 2015 and we're still [short of 100% coverage](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/)

Comment: Thanks. I tought Microsoft would no longer support IE11, but reading https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsforbusiness/end-of-ie-support I see that the latest version still receives updates.

Comment: I will add, too, that part of the beauty of TypeScript is precisely that it allows you to use the ES6/7 features of tomorrow *today*, compiled down to ES5/IE11 compatible code.  Examples: classes, let and const keywords, template strings, async/await, etc etc.